# javascript recursive function wrong answer

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here's [my code's jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBqKw/5/). t

```
function test(i)
{
  if(i==2)
      return {title:"finished at 2", data:"empty"}
  else
  {
          a=[]
          a.push(test(i+1))
          a.push(test(i+1))
          return {title:"number "+i, data:a}
    }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(test(0)))
```

Here, `test(0)` should be

```
{
    title: "number 0",
    data: [{
        title: "number 1",
        data: [{
            title: "finished at 2",
            data: "Empty"
        }, {
            title: "finished at 2",
            data: "Empty"
        }]
    }, {
        title: "number 1",
        data: [{
            title: "finished at 2",
            data: "Empty"
        }, {
            title: "finished at 2",
            data: "Empty"
        }]
    }]
```

while you can see it is different in the code's result. How and Why? What do I do to make it right?

Comment: Clarify your question please.

Comment: This is not what die Fiddle shows!

Comment: You might consider using `console.log()` in the future instead of `alert()`. Not an answer though.

Comment: @Furqan oops!! sorry, forgot to update the fiddle and the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a global variable in your recursive function, so it will be changed while you are using it.

Change this:

```
a = []
```

to:

```
var a = []
```